# PasswordHash not working php CI

Tags: php, passwords, password-hash

I followed the tutorial  http://dialect.ca/code/ci-simple-login-secure/
but I am having a password error 
when I enter the password

```
M@ndiri%%321 and M@ndiri%%654
```

at any rate having reversed my password error..
if there is a problem in the regex?

how to fix??..thanks

Comment: Could you share the regex?

Comment: './0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

Answer (score 1):

According to the regex shown above, you shouldn't have anything except alphanumeric characters but as you can see, you have a few special characters in your password string :)

The expression above may be written like this `/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g` as well. Or like this `/([[:alnum:]+])/g`

If you want to add special characters use this `/([ -~]+)/g`. This will allow you to use (english) alphanumeric and special characters .

Or use this `/([a-zA-Z0-9%@#$]+)/g` if you want to allow alphanumeric and just the special characters mentioned below in your comment.

How to use the pattern above with PHP

```
$password = "aH8J9%3$%";
if(!preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9%@#$]+)$/", $password)){
    echo "Invalid password!";
}
```

How to use it with JavaScript

```
var pattern = /^([a-zA-Z0-9%@#$]+)$/g;
var password = document.getElementById("password").value; // aH8J9%3$%
if(!pattern.test(password)){
    alert("Invalid password!");
}
```

Comment: if want to use % and @ # $ ..how to add regex?

Comment: @ArdyAnt Glad I could help. Could you please add `regex` tag to your answer since this is related to it :)

Comment: sorry I added /^(?=\S*?[A-Z])(?=\S*?[a-z])(?=\S*?[0-9])(?=\S*?[^\w\*])\S{5,}$/ but still there is an error when read the password

Comment: @ArdyAnt Where did you get this :) Why not using one of the expressions shown above. Anyhow, let me check this one - looks quite messy :) Or the better way, just tell me what pattern would you like to have, or even better, I'll give you the pattern I use.

Comment: I followed this tutorial https://github.com/DaBourz/SimpleLoginSecure/blob/master/phpass-0.3/PasswordHash.php  ..how to add regex in line 35

Comment: @ArdyAnt This `/^(?=\S*?[A-Z])(?=\S*?[a-z])(?=\S*?[0-9])(?=\S*?[^\w*])\S{5,}$/` is saying give me one A-Z, then one a-Z, then one 0-9, then one special char in this order and be sure to enter another any char except white-space since according to this you need at least five charasters. In other words this `Aa0^d6` would pass but not this one `98a*9u` (because of the order).

Comment: @ArdyAnt Oh I see you unaccepted the answer. Well, would you tell what went wrong :) and I'll try to help you.

Comment: thanks.I tried another way.. to validate% with javascript..but if php how could it be better..thanks broo

Comment: @ArdyAnt I updated the answer so you can see how to use the Regex with PHP or JavaScript.